# Insert image into video file

Tags: ios

I need to be able to override a section of a recorded video file with an image. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. If somebody could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, you'll be able to access the `moviePlayerController.currentPlaybackTime`. Given that, one solution to your problem could be 
1. Determine the start and end times of what you want to cover up. 
2. Monitor the currentPlaybackTime with a [Timer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html). 
3. Place your image over the video during your time window and remove it after the time window has passed.

Comment: This solution would work fine, but I need to be able to actually modify the video file itself. I will probably end up writing a server component to do this, it looks like there's a few C++ libraries I can use.